Why std::make_format_args expects a non-const reference
Looking at the documentation, I don't understand why std::make_format_args() takes a reference and not a const reference?
My goal is to implement something like:
#include <format>

template <class... Args>
inline static std::string format(const std::string_view field, Args&&... args)
{ 
    return std::vformat(field, std::make_format_args(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); 
}

And being able to pass const std::string& as input in args, but it seems like std::make_format_args() expects a non-const reference.
I get an error:
A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\format(3713): note: see declaration of 'std::make_format_args'
note: while trying to match the argument list '(_Ty, const std::string, _Ty, _Ty)'

UPDATE
I can reproduce the error here: https://godbolt.org/z/nj763o48r (locally I get the exact same error as above)

Where does the documentation say the function doesn't accept const references? Even the example code uses const references.

template< class Context = std::format_context, class... Args > /format-arg-store/<Context, Args...>  make_format_args( Args&... args );

does your code not compile? Whats the issue with what you want to implement? It seems like you already reached the goal. Why not?

I put error in the description

I couldn't it used to work and can't find which line sorry will try

example for how T& can be deduced as const T& and for no errors from your code https://godbolt.org/z/PPWTeE98M (from deleted answer)

I reproduce the error!!

@SpeakX, your godbolt link is just to the general godbolt page. You need to get a sharable link from the menu in the top bar on the site.

DONE shared the link

@SpeakX Your question itself has been answered, but to fix your code, just don't call std::forward on args. E.g. working version of your example: https://godbolt.org/z/6vd5eeWj4

Because of the poor user experience and safety issues detailed in Defect Report P2905R2. The issue, (summaries taken from the bottom of the documentation page) was that "make_format_args accepted rvalue arguments by forwarding references", and the resolution was that make_format_args "only takes lvalue references".

How can I do what I want and what is the difference between fmt and format please

@SpeakX Have you tried simply not using forwarding references and just accepting Args&... like the standard function does? And {fmt} is basically the library that std::format was based on (though since it didn't have to get everything through the standardization process, it is not 100% the same).

Will try that. I reproduce the error. I updated my question!!
